# Is it safe to trust $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?

Tags: php, security, ip-address

Is it safe to trust `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`? Can it be substituted by changing the header of request or something like that?

Is it safe to write something like that?

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '222.222.222.222') { // my ip address
    $grant_all_admin_rights = true;
}
```

Comment: Adding to the existing answers, it will always be the IP address that made the request to your server, but that doesn't mean it's the IP address of the computer that started the request. Any number of proxy servers could be in-between you and the end user, and the closest one to you is the IP address you get.

Comment: yes it's safe because can't be subtituted by another tricks or some cheating. but make sure you add more check for $grant_all_admin_rights variable.

Comment: Any $_SERVER variable can be spoofed - e.g. curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip")); So it depends entirely on the context: if the attacker is expecting a response, it will go back to $ip.  If they don't care about the response, they can certainly spoof the header.  If your code after the header check instead said: "open_the_door_to_badguys();" you would have a problem.

Comment: @TMG You can't spoof the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable by setting an HTTP request header. PHP automatically prefixes all HTTP request headers with `HTTP_` when creating keys in the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. It is the source IP of the TCP connection and can't be substituted by changing an HTTP header.

One case you may want to be worry of is if you are behind a reverse proxy in which case the REMOTE_ADDR will always be the IP of the proxy server and the user IP will be provided in an HTTP header (such as [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)). But for the normal use case reading REMOTE_ADDR is fine.

Comment: What about IP address spoofing?

Comment: @Abdull The people who can do that are usually the same people who have physical access to your box. so don't worry about it that much.

Comment: @Abdull IP spoofing can only send messages one way, you can't spoof your IP and get a message in return.

Comment: Aren't internet routers checking the source and destination IP to route packets? I doubt that a spoofed packet will ever reach the destination across internet nodes.

Answer (score 59):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the IP address the TCP connection came in on. While it is technically possible to bidirectionally spoof IP addresses on the Internet (by announcing foul routes via BGP), such attacks are likely to be spotted and not available to the typical attacker - basically, your attacker must have control over an ISP or carrier. There are no feasible unidirectional spoofing attacks against TCP (yet). Bidirectional IP spoofing is trivial on a LAN though.

Also be aware that it may be not be an IPv4, but an IPv6 address. Your current check is fine in that regard, but if you would check that `1.2.3.4` only occurs *anywhere* within `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, an attacker could simply connect from `2001:1234:5678::1.2.3.4`.

Summarily, for anything other than critical (banking/military/potential damage >50.000€) applications, you can use the remote IP address if you can exclude attackers in your local network.

Comment: You sound very informed about the Internet Protocol.

Comment: @phihag, Whether `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the IP address the TCP connection came in on depends entirely on your SAPI.

Comment: its far from infeasable for an attacker on a WEP/WPA WLAN to kick the real client off, and spoof that ip address - both WEP and WPA have weaknesses that makes spoofing `you have been kicked off the wlan` packets easy to create with the right tools. google `WPA downgrade test`, for instance

Comment: The IP address is IP level not TCP level.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above, it's not absolutely safe. But it doesn't mean, that you shouldn't use it. Consider combine this with some other methods of authentication, for instance checking COOKIE values.

Comment: After spoofing an IP address, changing the http request and sending false cookies is a piece of cake.....  (or a piece of cookie)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not absolutely safe"