# How to fwrite before a specific tag </file>

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fopen, fwrite

I am making a script in which php will fwrite and it ads it after the </file> tag and it doesnt get included. The main purpose is to log each IP in this .htaccess file in order to not have access to this specific file. Here is my code: (Searching about 3+ hours on google & php.net). I have thought if there is a way to read from the file .htaccess where the "word" </file> is and before it add the $ip. Or some other way to get the $badpersonip inside the <file forum.php
*(I can not use a database so it needs to be done solely from PHP and .htaccess)

```
<?php

$badpersonip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

echo "You have been banned $badpersonip , dont spam!! <br> ";
$ip = "deny from $badpersonip \n";
$banip = '.htaccess';
$fp = fopen($banip, "a");
$write = fputs($fp, $ip);

?>
```

Also here is my .htaccess code:

```
<files forum.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all

deny from 127.0.2.1
deny from 127.1.2.1

</files>
deny from 127.0.0.3
```

As you see it ads the new IP but on the bottom AFTER the files tag has closed. :(

Thank you for your help really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If instead of using `fwrite()` you read the whole thing into a string with [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), you can easily do `str_replace()` to replace the existing `</files>` with the new line and `</files>`

```
// Read the while file into a string $htaccess
$htaccess = file_get_contents('.htaccess');
// Stick the new IP just before the closing </files>
$new_htaccess = str_replace('</files>', "deny from $badpersonip\n</files>", $htaccess);
// And write the new string back to the file
file_put_contents('.htaccess', $new_htaccess);
```

This isn't recommended if you expect the file to become very large, but for a few dozen or few hundred IPs it should work fine.  This won't work exactly as is if you have more than one `</files>` in that .htaccess file. That would require more careful parsing to find the correct closing tag.

If preserving whitespace (if you have indentation before `</files>`) is important to you, you look into using `preg_replace()` in lieu of the simpler `str_replace()`.

Another method to this would be to use `file()` to read the .htaccess into an array of its lines, locate the line containing `</files>` and insert a new array element before it then join the lines back together and write it to the file.

Comment: Thank you very much just tried the script with the edit, it gives me only the new part and deletes the before part. Output is: 
deny from 127.0.0.1
</files>

Why isnt it joining the .htaccess with the $new_htaccess? Instead it only outputs in the .htaccess the $new_htaccess. 
I am still "beginner" in php so I wouldnt want to complicate the things too much there wont be that many IPs to ban. I havent gotten to arrays yet.

Comment: @MagicHown Sorry, I have the args in the wrong order for str_replace(). try again... The original string subject goes last not first.

Comment: Trully thank you very very much Michael, it worked perfectly!! I will keep in mind the clearing of the log in case of it getting big. Is there any security concern you would see in this such file? If someone spoofs their ip to lets say googlebot's and gets them self banned if I have already added the ip in the allow section will the deny it will get afterwards delete the previous allow? I will try to later create a MYSQL DB to set rules as in ip != to googlebot and other known bots.But for the current time other than the "google" banning crawler problem I dont see anything else do you?Thankyou

Comment: @MagicHown You are correct to think about possible abuse. The same problems arise for any auto-ban system.  If your htaccess is configured to allow first then deny via the directive `Allow, deny`, you can always explicitly list any allowed addresses before the denials are placed and any subsequent deny rule on that address will have no effect.  Since you are using `REMOTE_ADDR`, [it is pretty safe from being spoofed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773969/is-it-safe-to-trust-serverremote-addr)