# Getting visitors country from their IP

Tags: php, geolocation, ip, country-codes

I want to get visitors country via their IP... Right now I'm using this (http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=...... )

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
    $real_ip_adress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
    $real_ip_adress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else
{
    $real_ip_adress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$cip = $real_ip_adress;
$iptolocation = 'http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=' . $cip;
$creatorlocation = file_get_contents($iptolocation);

?>
```

Well, it's working properly, but the thing is, this returns the country code like US or CA., and not the whole country name like United States or Canada.

So, is there any good alternative to hostip.info offers this?

I know that I can just write some code that will eventually turn this two letters to whole country name, but I'm just too lazy to write a code that contains all countries...

P.S: For some reason I don't want to use any ready made CSV file or any code that will grab this information for me, something like ip2country ready made code and CSV.

Comment: Don't be lazy, there aren't that many countries, and it's not too hard to obtain a translation table for FIPS 2 letter codes to country names.

Comment: Use Maxmind geoip feature. It will include the country name in the results. http://www.maxmind.com/app/php

Comment: Your first assignment to `$real_ip_address` is always ignored. Anyways, remember that the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header can be extremely easily counterfeited, and that there are proxies like www.hidemyass.com

Comment: IPLocate.io provides a free API: [`https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8`](https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8) - Disclaimer: I run this service.

Comment: I suggest giving a try to [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co): 

https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout&fields=location.country&pretty=true

(disclaimer: I run the service).

Answer (score 587, accepted):

**Try this simple PHP function.**

```
<?php

function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    $output = NULL;
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
    $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
    $continents = array(
        "AF" => "Africa",
        "AN" => "Antarctica",
        "AS" => "Asia",
        "EU" => "Europe",
        "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
        "NA" => "North America",
        "SA" => "South America"
    );
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
        $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
        if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
            switch ($purpose) {
                case "location":
                    $output = array(
                        "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                        "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                        "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                        "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                        "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                        "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                    );
                    break;
                case "address":
                    $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                    break;
                case "city":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    break;
                case "state":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "region":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "country":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                    break;
                case "countrycode":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

?>
```

**How to use:**

*Example1: Get visitor IP address details*

```
<?php

echo ip_info("Visitor", "Country"); // India
echo ip_info("Visitor", "Country Code"); // IN
echo ip_info("Visitor", "State"); // Andhra Pradesh
echo ip_info("Visitor", "City"); // Proddatur
echo ip_info("Visitor", "Address"); // Proddatur, Andhra Pradesh, India

print_r(ip_info("Visitor", "Location")); // Array ( [city] => Proddatur [state] => Andhra Pradesh [country] => India [country_code] => IN [continent] => Asia [continent_code] => AS )

?>
```

*Example 2: Get details of any IP address. [Support IPV4 & IPV6]*

```
<?php

echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Country"); // United States
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Country Code"); // US
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "State"); // California
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "City"); // Menlo Park
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Address"); // Menlo Park, California, United States

print_r(ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Location")); // Array ( [city] => Menlo Park [state] => California [country] => United States [country_code] => US [continent] => North America [continent_code] => NA )

?>
```

Comment: why im getting unknow all the time with every ip ? , used same code.

Comment: You get "Unknown" probably because your server does not allow `file_get_contents()`. Just check your error_log file. Workaround: see my answer.

Comment: also it might be because u check it localy (192.168.1.1 / 127.0.0.1 / 10.0.0.1)

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV I can not get the country name as well, when I echo $cip, $iptolocation and $creatorlocation I get this: 10.48.44.43http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=10.48.44.43XX , why it returns xx for country?

Comment: @Antonimo: I can not get the country name as well, when I echo $cip, $iptolocation and $creatorlocation I get this: 10.48.44.43http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=10.48.44.43XX , why it returns xx for country? –

Comment: anything starting with 10. is a local ip, check the manuals/wiki

Comment: @echo_Me Maybe your server failed to connecting `geoplugin.net` API server.

Comment: Keep getting 'undefined' for my country

Comment: @madcrazydrumma What is your IP?

Comment: @ChandraNakka 127.0.0.1 is the localhost server, my ip is currently 197.234.10.142 which should be in the Seychelles

Comment: Remember to cache the results for a defined period. Also, as a note, you should never rely on another website to get any data, the website might go down, the service could stop, etc. And if you get an increased number of visitors on your website, this service could ban you.

Comment: Does this require user authorization just like how Geolocation did?

Comment: echo ip_info("Visitor", "Country Code"); returns NULL

Comment: Follow on: this is an issue when testing a site on localhost. Any way to fix for testing purposes? Uses the standard 127.0.0.1 localhost IP

Comment: It should be noted that `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` used in the `deep_detect` option will get you the real IP of the user if he is using a **proxy server** -transparent proxy offcurse - , not the IP of the proxy server which is the client how is actually tcp-connected to my website. Thanks for this great answer

Comment: I can't make this work. I have copied the function and tried the first example and there is not a single echo or print on the page.

Comment: This is awesome i've been looking for something like this for a while, well done!

Comment: It uses object reference -> but the response is array change all to [''] instead.Also should get rid of all this @ suppresses.And also using curl is much better than file_get_contents.

Comment: Suppressing errors with `@` was bad practice 10 years ago and is still a bad practice now.

Answer (score 60):

You can use a simple API from http://www.geoplugin.net/

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=".getRealIpAddr());
echo $xml->geoplugin_countryName ;


echo "<pre>";
foreach ($xml as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key , "= " , $value ,  " \n" ;
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Function Used

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Output

```
United States
geoplugin_city= San Antonio
geoplugin_region= TX
geoplugin_areaCode= 210
geoplugin_dmaCode= 641
geoplugin_countryCode= US
geoplugin_countryName= United States
geoplugin_continentCode= NA
geoplugin_latitude= 29.488899230957
geoplugin_longitude= -98.398696899414
geoplugin_regionCode= TX
geoplugin_regionName= Texas
geoplugin_currencyCode= USD
geoplugin_currencySymbol= $
geoplugin_currencyConverter= 1
```

It makes you have so many options you can play around with

Thanks

:)

Comment: That's really cool. But while testing here are no values in the following fields "geoplugin_city, geoplugin_region, geoplugin_regionCode, geoplugin_regionName".. What is the reason? Is there any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: it's now actually geoplugin.com.... which.... you probably can refer to the other example (above)

Answer (score 38):

I tried Chandra's answer but my server configuration does not allow **file_get_contents()**

`PHP Warning: file_get_contents() URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration`

I modified Chandra's code so that it also works for servers like that using cURL:

```
function ip_visitor_country()
{

    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $country  = "Unknown";

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $ip_data_in = curl_exec($ch); // string
    curl_close($ch);

    $ip_data = json_decode($ip_data_in,true);
    $ip_data = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $ip_data); // for PHP 5.2 see stackoverflow.com/questions/3110487/

    if($ip_data && $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'] != null) {
        $country = $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'];
    }

    return 'IP: '.$ip.' # Country: '.$country;
}

echo ip_visitor_country(); // output Coutry name

?>
```

Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: According to the docs on their site: "If geoplugin.net was responding perfectly, then stopped, then you have gone over the free lookup limit of 120 requests per minute. "

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: I have not tested this but voted up for using **curl** as **allow_url_fopen** is generally disabled in most servers. It should work anyway.

Answer (score 15):

Use MaxMind GeoIP (or GeoIPLite if you are not ready to pay).

```
$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
```

Comment: @Joyce: I tried to use Maxmind API and DB, but I don't know why it does not work for me, actually it works in general, but for instance when I run this $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];it shows me this ip : 10.48.44.43, but when i use it in geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip), it returns nothing, any idea?

Comment: It is a reserved ip address (internal ip address from your local network). Try running the code on a remote server.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a web-service from http://ip-api.com
in your php code, do as follow :

```
<?php
$ip = $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
  echo 'Hello visitor from '.$query['country'].', '.$query['city'].'!';
} else {
  echo 'Unable to get location';
}
?>
```

the query have many other informations:

```
array (
  'status'      => 'success',
  'country'     => 'COUNTRY',
  'countryCode' => 'COUNTRY CODE',
  'region'      => 'REGION CODE',
  'regionName'  => 'REGION NAME',
  'city'        => 'CITY',
  'zip'         => ZIP CODE,
  'lat'         => LATITUDE,
  'lon'         => LONGITUDE,
  'timezone'    => 'TIME ZONE',
  'isp'         => 'ISP NAME',
  'org'         => 'ORGANIZATION NAME',
  'as'          => 'AS NUMBER / NAME',
  'query'       => 'IP ADDRESS USED FOR QUERY',
)
```

Comment: Used ip-api.com because they also supply ISP name!

Comment: I Used because they also supply the Timezone

Answer (score 13):

Actually, you can call http://api.hostip.info/?ip=123.125.114.144 to get the information, which is presented in XML.

Answer (score 11):

Check out [php-ip-2-country](http://code.google.com/p/php-ip-2-country/) from code.google. The database they provide is updated daily, so it is not necessary to connect to an outside server for the check if you host your own SQL server. So using the code you would only have to type:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(!empty($ip)){
        require('./phpip2country.class.php');

        /**
         * Newest data (SQL) avaliable on project website
         * @link http://code.google.com/p/php-ip-2-country/
         */
        $dbConfigArray = array(
                'host' => 'localhost', //example host name
                'port' => 3306, //3306 -default mysql port number
                'dbName' => 'ip_to_country', //example db name
                'dbUserName' => 'ip_to_country', //example user name
                'dbUserPassword' => 'QrDB9Y8CKMdLDH8Q', //example user password
                'tableName' => 'ip_to_country', //example table name
        );

        $phpIp2Country = new phpIp2Country($ip,$dbConfigArray);
        $country = $phpIp2Country->getInfo(IP_COUNTRY_NAME);
        echo $country;
?>
```

**Example Code** *(from the resource)*

```
<?
require('phpip2country.class.php');

$dbConfigArray = array(
        'host' => 'localhost', //example host name
        'port' => 3306, //3306 -default mysql port number
        'dbName' => 'ip_to_country', //example db name
        'dbUserName' => 'ip_to_country', //example user name
        'dbUserPassword' => 'QrDB9Y8CKMdLDH8Q', //example user password
        'tableName' => 'ip_to_country', //example table name
);

$phpIp2Country = new phpIp2Country('213.180.138.148',$dbConfigArray);

print_r($phpIp2Country->getInfo(IP_INFO));
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [IP_FROM] => 3585376256
    [IP_TO] => 3585384447
    [REGISTRY] => RIPE
    [ASSIGNED] => 948758400
    [CTRY] => PL
    [CNTRY] => POL
    [COUNTRY] => POLAND
    [IP_STR] => 213.180.138.148
    [IP_VALUE] => 3585378964
    [IP_FROM_STR] => 127.255.255.255
    [IP_TO_STR] => 127.255.255.255
)
```

Comment: we must provide database information to work ? seems not good.

Answer (score 10):

Use following services

1) http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19

2)

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.appspot.com/json/66.102.13.106');
$expression = json_decode($json);
print_r($expression);
```

3) http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Answer (score 10):

We can use geobytes.com to get the location using user IP address

```
$user_ip = getIP();
$meta_tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IPLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IPAddress=' . $user_ip);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($meta_tags);
```

it will return data like this

```
Array(
    [known] => true
    [locationcode] => USCALANG
    [fips104] => US
    [iso2] => US
    [iso3] => USA
    [ison] => 840
    [internet] => US
    [countryid] => 254
    [country] => United States
    [regionid] => 126
    [region] => California
    [regioncode] => CA
    [adm1code] =>     
    [cityid] => 7275
    [city] => Los Angeles
    [latitude] => 34.0452
    [longitude] => -118.2840
    [timezone] => -08:00
    [certainty] => 53
    [mapbytesremaining] => Free
)
```

Function to get user IP

```
function getIP(){
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){
    $pattern = "/^(([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/";
    if(preg_match($pattern, $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){
            $userIP = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }else{
            $userIP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
}
else{
  $userIP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
return $userIP;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, it returns this for me:   Array
(
    [known] => false
)

Comment: when I try this : $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; echo $ip; it returns it :   10.48.44.43, do you know what is the problem?? I used alspo maxmind geoip, and when I used geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, $ip) againit returned me nothing...

Comment: @mOna, it return your ip address. for more details pls, share your code.

Comment: I found that problem is realted to my ip since it is for private network. then I fuond my real ip in ifconfig and used it in my program. then it worked:) Now, my question is how to get real ip in case of those users similar to me? (if they use local ip).. I wrote my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958564/php-country-dropdown-by-maxmind-geoip

Answer (score 9):

Try this simple one line code, You will get country and city of visitors from  their ip remote address.

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $tags['country'];
echo $tags['city'];
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a well-maintained flat-file version of the ip->country database maintained by the Perl community at [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/release/IP-Country)

Access to those files does not require a dataserver, and the data itself is roughly 515k

Higemaru has written a PHP wrapper to talk to that data: [php-ip-country-fast](https://github.com/higemaru/php-ip-country-fast)

Comment: Database is outdated, last update 2013. There is guide on how you can create the database yourself tho, using the 4 regional registries, but I didnt test it if still works

Answer (score 6):

Many different ways to do it...

## **Solution #1:**

One third party service you could use is http://ipinfodb.com. They provide hostname, geolocation and additional information.

Register for an API key here: http://ipinfodb.com/register.php. This will allow you to retrieve results from their server, without this it will not work.

Copy and past the following PHP code:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE';

$data = file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=$api_key&ip=$ipaddress&format=json");
$data = json_decode($data);
$country = $data['Country'];
```

**Downside:**

Quoting from their website:

> Our free API is using IP2Location Lite version which provides lower
>   accuracy.

## **Solution #2:**

This function will return country name using the http://www.netip.de/ service.

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
function geoCheckIP($ip)
{
    $response=@file_get_contents('http://www.netip.de/search?query='.$ip);

    $patterns=array();
    $patterns["country"] = '#Country: (.*?)&nbsp;#i';

    $ipInfo=array();

    foreach ($patterns as $key => $pattern)
    {
        $ipInfo[$key] = preg_match($pattern,$response,$value) && !empty($value[1]) ? $value[1] : 'not found';
    }

        return $ipInfo;
}

print_r(geoCheckIP($ipaddress));
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [country] => DE - Germany )  // Full Country Name
```

Comment: Quoting from their website: "You are limited to 1,000 API requests per day. If you need to make more requests, or need SSL support, see our paid plans."

Comment: I used it on my personal website so that is why I posted it. Thank you for the info... didn't realize it. I put much more effort on the post, so please see the updated post :)

Comment: @imbondbaby: Hi, I tried your code, but for me it returns this :Array ( [country] => - ), I do not understand the problem since when i try to print this: $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; it shows me this ip : 10.48.44.43, I can't understand why this ip does not work! I mean wherever I insert this number it does not return any country!!! counld u plz help me?

Answer (score 6):

My service [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-12553160&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) provides the country name in 5 languages! As well as the organisation, currency, timezone, calling code, flag, Mobile Carrier data, Proxy data and Tor Exit Node status data from any IPv4 or IPv6 address.

> This answer uses a 'test' API Key that is very limited and only meant for testing a few calls. [Signup](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-12553160-free-plan-cta&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) for your own Free API Key and get up to 1500 requests daily for development.

It's also extremely scalable with 10 regions around the world each able to handle >10,000 requests per second!

The options include; English (en), German (de), Japanese (ja), French (fr) and Simplified Chinese (za-CH)

```
$ip = '74.125.230.195';
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.ipdata.co/{$ip}?api-key=test"));
echo $details->country_name;
//United States
echo $details->city;
//Mountain View
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.ipdata.co/{$ip}?api-key=test/zh-CN"));
echo $details->country_name;
//美国
```

Comment: God bless you, man! I got more than what I asked for! Quick question: can I use it for prod? I mean, you're not going to put it down anytime soon, are you?

Comment: Not at all :) I'm in fact adding more regions and more polish. Glad you found this to be of help :)

Comment: Very helpful, specially with the additional params, solved more than one problem for me!

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback! I built around the most common usecases for such a tool, the goal was to eliminate having to do any additional processing after the geolocation, happy to see this paying off for users

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is a new service but now (2016) the easiest way in php is to use geoplugin's php web service: http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp:

**Basic usage:**

```
// GET IP ADDRESS
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
} else {
    $ip = false;
}

// CALL THE WEBSERVICE
$ip_info = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip));
```

They also provide a ready built class: http://www.geoplugin.com/_media/webservices/geoplugin.class.php.tgz?id=webservices%3Aphp&cache=cache

Comment: You used an `else` after `else` which causes an error. What did you try to prevent? REMOTE_ADDR should be available all the time?

Comment: @Vaia - Perhaps it *should be* but you never know.

Comment: Is there a case where it isnt available you know of?

Comment: @Vaia - from the PHP docs on `$_SERVER`: *"There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here."*

Comment: Note there is a limit to requests; from their site: "If geoplugin.net was responding perfectly, then stopped, then you have gone over the free lookup limit of 120 requests per minute. "

Answer (score 4):

Would that be acceptable ?
pure PHP

```
$country = geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
print $country;
```

ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php

Comment: note that this only works with the GeoIP PECL extension of PHP installed (which is by default not bundled).

Comment: Debian installation: sudo apt install php-geoip

Answer (score 3):

you can use  http://ipinfo.io/ to get details of ip address Its easy to use .

```
<?php
    function ip_details($ip)
    {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
    $details = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
    }

    $details = ip_details(YoUR IP ADDRESS); 

    echo $details->city;
    echo "<br>".$details->country; 
    echo "<br>".$details->org; 
    echo "<br>".$details->hostname; /

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

A one liner with an [IP address to country](https://ipapi.co/) API

```
echo file_get_contents('https://ipapi.co/8.8.8.8/country_name/');

> United States
```

Example :

https://ipapi.co/country_name/ - your country

https://ipapi.co/8.8.8.8/country_name/ - country for IP 8.8.8.8

Comment: This API allows 1000 (free) API calls per day.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `ipinfodb.com` api and getting exactly what you are looking for.

Its completely free, you just need to register with them to get your api key. You can include their php class by downloading from their website or you can use url format to retrieve information.

Here's what I am doing:

I included their php class in my script and using the below code:

```
$ipLite = new ip2location_lite;
$ipLite->setKey('your_api_key');
if(!$_COOKIE["visitorCity"]){ //I am using cookie to store information
  $visitorCity = $ipLite->getCity($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  if ($visitorCity['statusCode'] == 'OK') {
    $data = base64_encode(serialize($visitorCity));
    setcookie("visitorCity", $data, time()+3600*24*7); //set cookie for 1 week
  }
}
$visitorCity = unserialize(base64_decode($_COOKIE["visitorCity"]));
echo $visitorCity['countryName'].' Region'.$visitorCity['regionName'];
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Replace *`127.0.0.1`* with visitors IpAddress.

```
$country = geoip_country_name_by_name('127.0.0.1');
```

Installation instructions are [here](http://php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php), and [read this to know how to obtain City, State, Country, Longitude, Latitude, etc...](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)

Comment: Please provide more actual code than just hard links.

Comment: Later news from the link: "As of January 2, 2019 Maxmind discontinued the original GeoLite databases that we have been using in all these examples. You can read the full announcement here: https://support.maxmind.com/geolite-legacy-discontinuation-notice/"

Answer (score 2):

I have a short answer which I have used in a project.
In my answer, I consider that you have visitor IP address.

```
$ip = "202.142.178.220";
$ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
//get ISO2 country code
if(property_exists($ipdat, 'geoplugin_countryCode')) {
    echo $ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
}
//get country full name
if(property_exists($ipdat, 'geoplugin_countryName')) {
    echo $ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have written a class based on "Chandra Nakka" answer. Hopefully it can help people out it saves the information from geoplugin to a session so the load is much faster when recalling the information. It also saves the values to a private array so recalling in the same code is the fastest as it could be.

```
class Geo {
private $_ip = null;
private $_useSession = true;
private $_sessionNameData = 'GEO_SESSION_DATA';
private $_hasError = false;
private $_geoData = [];

const PURPOSE_SUPPORT = [
    "all", "*", "location",
    "request",
    "latitude", 
    "longitude",
    "accuracy",
    "timezonde",
    "currencycode",
    "currencysymbol",
    "currencysymbolutf8",
    "country", 
    "countrycode", 
    "state", "region", 
    "city", 
    "address",
    "continent", 
    "continentcode"
];
const CONTINENTS = [
    "AF" => "Africa",
    "AN" => "Antarctica",
    "AS" => "Asia",
    "EU" => "Europe",
    "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
    "NA" => "North America",
    "SA" => "South America"
];

function __construct($ip = null, $deepDetect = true, $useSession = true)
{
    // define the session useage within this class
    $this->_useSession = $useSession;
    $this->_startSession();

    // define a ip as far as possible
    $this->_ip = $this->_defineIP($ip, $deepDetect);

    // check if the ip was set
    if (!$this->_ip) {
        $this->_hasError = true;
        return $this;
    }

    // define the geoData
    $this->_geoData = $this->_fetchGeoData();

    return $this;
}

function get($purpose)
{
    // making sure its lowercase
    $purpose = strtolower($purpose);

    // makeing sure there are no error and the geodata is not empty
    if ($this->_hasError || !count($this->_geoData) && !in_array($purpose, self::PURPOSE_SUPPORT)) {
        return 'error';
    }

    if (in_array($purpose, ['*', 'all', 'location']))  {
        return $this->_geoData;
    }

    if ($purpose === 'state') $purpose = 'region';

    return (isset($this->_geoData[$purpose]) ? $this->_geoData[$purpose] : 'missing: '.$purpose);
}

private function _fetchGeoData()
{
    // check if geo data was set before
    if (count($this->_geoData)) {
        return $this->_geoData;
    }

    // check possible session
    if ($this->_useSession && ($sessionData = $this->_getSession($this->_sessionNameData))) {
        return $sessionData;
    }

    // making sure we have a valid ip
    if (!$this->_ip || $this->_ip === '127.0.0.1') {
        return [];
    }

    // fetch the information from geoplusing
    $ipdata = @json_decode($this->curl("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $this->_ip));

    // check if the data was fetched
    if (!@strlen(trim($ipdata->geoplugin_countryCode)) === 2) {
        return [];
    }

    // make a address array
    $address = [$ipdata->geoplugin_countryName];
    if (@strlen($ipdata->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
        $address[] = $ipdata->geoplugin_regionName;
    if (@strlen($ipdata->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
        $address[] = $ipdata->geoplugin_city;

    // makeing sure the continentCode is upper case
    $continentCode = strtoupper(@$ipdata->geoplugin_continentCode);

    $geoData = [
        'request' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_request,
        'latitude' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_latitude,
        'longitude' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_longitude,
        'accuracy' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_locationAccuracyRadius,
        'timezonde' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_timezone,
        'currencycode' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_currencyCode,
        'currencysymbol' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_currencySymbol,
        'currencysymbolutf8' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8,
        'city' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_city,
        'region' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_regionName,
        'country' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_countryName,
        'countrycode' => @$ipdata->geoplugin_countryCode,
        'continent' => self::CONTINENTS[$continentCode],
        'continentcode' => $continentCode,
        'address' => implode(", ", array_reverse($address))
    ];

    if ($this->_useSession) {
        $this->_setSession($this->_sessionNameData, $geoData);
    }

    return $geoData;
}

private function _startSession()
{
    // only start a new session when the status is 'none' and the class
    // requires a session
    if ($this->_useSession && session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
}

private function _defineIP($ip, $deepDetect)
{
    // check if the ip was set before
    if ($this->_ip) {
        return $this->_ip;
    }

    // check if the ip given is valid
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        return $ip;
    }

    // try to get the ip from the REMOTE_ADDR
    $ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REMOTE_ADDR', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);

    // check if we need to end the search for a IP if the REMOTE_ADDR did not
    // return a valid and the deepDetect is false
    if (!$deepDetect) {
        return $ip;
    }

    // try to get the ip from HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
    if (($ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))) {
        return $ip;
    }

    // try to get the ip from the HTTP_CLIENT_IP
    if (($ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))) {
        return $ip;
    }

    return $ip;
}

private function _hasSession($key, $filter = FILTER_DEFAULT) 
{
    return (isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? (bool)filter_var($_SESSION[$key], $filter) : false);
}

private function _getSession($key, $filter = FILTER_DEFAULT)
{
    if ($this->_hasSession($key, $filter)) {
        $value = filter_var($_SESSION[$key], $filter);

        if (@json_decode($value)) {
            return json_decode($value, true);
        }

        return filter_var($_SESSION[$key], $filter);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private function _setSession($key, $value) 
{
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = json_encode($value);
    }

    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}

function emptySession($key) {
    if (!$this->_hasSession($key)) {
        return;
    }

    $_SESSION[$key] = null;
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);

}

function curl($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
}
```

Answering the 'op' question with this class you can call

```
$country = (new \Geo())->get('country'); // United Kingdom
```

And the other properties available are:

```
$geo = new \Geo('185.35.50.4');
var_dump($geo->get('*')); // allias all / location
var_dump($geo->get('country'));
var_dump($geo->get('countrycode'));
var_dump($geo->get('state')); // allias region
var_dump($geo->get('city')); 
var_dump($geo->get('address')); 
var_dump($geo->get('continent')); 
var_dump($geo->get('continentcode'));   
var_dump($geo->get('request'));
var_dump($geo->get('latitude'));
var_dump($geo->get('longitude'));
var_dump($geo->get('accuracy'));
var_dump($geo->get('timezonde'));
var_dump($geo->get('currencyCode'));
var_dump($geo->get('currencySymbol'));
var_dump($geo->get('currencySymbolUTF8'));
```

Returning

```
array(15) {
  ["request"]=>
  string(11) "185.35.50.4"
  ["latitude"]=>
  string(7) "51.4439"
  ["longitude"]=>
  string(7) "-0.1854"
  ["accuracy"]=>
  string(2) "50"
  ["timezonde"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/London"
  ["currencycode"]=>
  string(3) "GBP"
  ["currencysymbol"]=>
  string(2) "£"
  ["currencysymbolutf8"]=>
  string(2) "£"
  ["city"]=>
  string(10) "Wandsworth"
  ["region"]=>
  string(10) "Wandsworth"
  ["country"]=>
  string(14) "United Kingdom"
  ["countrycode"]=>
  string(2) "GB"
  ["continent"]=>
  string(6) "Europe"
  ["continentcode"]=>
  string(2) "EU"
  ["address"]=>
  string(38) "Wandsworth, Wandsworth, United Kingdom"
}
string(14) "United Kingdom"
string(2) "GB"
string(10) "Wandsworth"
string(10) "Wandsworth"
string(38) "Wandsworth, Wandsworth, United Kingdom"
string(6) "Europe"
string(2) "EU"
string(11) "185.35.50.4"
string(7) "51.4439"
string(7) "-0.1854"
string(2) "50"
string(13) "Europe/London"
string(3) "GBP"
string(2) "£"
string(2) "£"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I tried a few other solutions on here and they seem to be outdated or just return null. So this is how I did it.

Using `http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=` which doesn't require any type of sign up or paying for the service.

```
function get_client_ip_server() {
  $ipaddress = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
  $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
  $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

  return $ipaddress;
}

$ipaddress = get_client_ip_server();

function getCountry($ip){
    $curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip='.$ip);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
    curl_close($curlSession);

    return $jsonData->geoplugin_countryCode;
}

echo "County: " .getCountry($ipaddress);
```

And if you want extra information about it, this is a full return of Json:

```
{
  "geoplugin_request":"IP_ADDRESS",
  "geoplugin_status":200,
  "geoplugin_delay":"2ms",
  "geoplugin_credit":"Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from <a href='http:\/\/www.maxmind.com'>http:\/\/www.maxmind.com<\/a>.",
  "geoplugin_city":"Current City",
  "geoplugin_region":"Region",
  "geoplugin_regionCode":"Region Code",
  "geoplugin_regionName":"Region Name",
  "geoplugin_areaCode":"",
  "geoplugin_dmaCode":"650",
  "geoplugin_countryCode":"US",
  "geoplugin_countryName":"United States",
  "geoplugin_inEU":0,
  "geoplugin_euVATrate":false,
  "geoplugin_continentCode":"NA",
  "geoplugin_continentName":"North America",
  "geoplugin_latitude":"37.5563",
  "geoplugin_longitude":"-99.9413",
  "geoplugin_locationAccuracyRadius":"5",
  "geoplugin_timezone":"America\/Chicago",
  "geoplugin_currencyCode":"USD",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol":"$",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8":"$",
  "geoplugin_currencyConverter":1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, MaxMind country DB can be used as follows:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use MaxMind\Db\Reader;
$databaseFile = 'GeoIP2-Country.mmdb';
$reader = new Reader($databaseFile);
$cc = $reader->get($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])['country']['iso_code'] # US/GB...
$reader->close();
```

---

Source:
https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-php

Comment: In case anyone considers this, know that this database has to be purchased.

Comment: There's a free version available.

Comment: oh… can you help me with an URL please? Wherever I looked, I always ended up at 3 payment options.

Comment: You've to [signup for GeoLite2](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geolite2/signup), but it's free to download after. https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ - "_To receive access to download the GeoLite2 databases at no charge, sign up for a GeoLite2 account._"

Answer (score 1):

PHP code to obtain country, city,
continent, etc using IP Address

```
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
      
    // Use JSON encoded string and converts 
    // it into a PHP variable 
    $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents( 
        "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip)); 
       
    $country = $ipdat->geoplugin_countryName; 
    $city = $ipdat->geoplugin_city; 
    $continent_name = $ipdat->geoplugin_continentName; 
    $latitude = $ipdat->geoplugin_latitude; 
    $longitude = $ipdat->geoplugin_longitude; 
    $currency_symbol = $ipdat->geoplugin_currencySymbol; 
    $currency_code = $ipdat->geoplugin_currencyCode; 
    $timezone = $ipdat->geoplugin_timezone;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippest.

```
 if($a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))){
        $countrycode= $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
        if ($countrycode=='UK' ){
            header( 'Location: https://www.example.co.uk/' ) ;exit;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [User Country API](https://usercountry.com) has exactly what you need. Here is a sample code using file_get_contents() as you originally do:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://usercountry.com/v1.0/json/'.$cip), true);
$result['country']['name']; // this contains what you need
```

Comment: This API allows 100 (free) API calls per day.

Answer (score 0):

You can get visitors country and city using ipstack geo API.You need to get your own ipstack API and then use the code below:

```
<?php
 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
 $api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY";
 $freegeoipjson = file_get_contents("http://api.ipstack.com/".$ip."?access_key=".$api_key."");
 $jsondata = json_decode($freegeoipjson);
 $countryfromip = $jsondata->country_name;
 echo "Country: ". $countryfromip ."";
?>
```

Source: **[Get visitors country and city in PHP using ipstack API](https://www.codespeedy.com/get-visitors-country-and-city-in-php-using-ipstack-api/)**

Answer (score 0):

**This is just a security note** on the functionality of `get_client_ip()` that most of the answers here have been included inside the main function of `get_geo_info_for_this_ip()`.

Don't rely too much on the IP data in the request headers like `Client-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For` because they can be spoofed very easily, however you should rely on the source IP of the TCP connection that is actually established between our server and the client `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` as [it can't be spoofed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773969/is-it-safe-to-trust-serverremote-addr)

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] // can be spoofed 
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] // can be spoofed 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']// can't be spoofed
```

It's OK to get the country of the spoofed IP but Keep in mind that using this IP in any security model (e.g: banning the IP that sends frequent requests) will destroy the entire security model. IMHO I prefer to use the actual client IP even if it is the IP of the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <?php
  //gives you the IP address of the visitors
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];}
  else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  } else {
      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }

  //return the country code
  $url = "http://api.wipmania.com/$ip";
  $country = file_get_contents($url);
  echo $country;

  ?>
```

Comment: The if-else part will give you the IP address of the visitor and the next part will return the country code. Try visiting http://api.wipmania.com/ and then http://api.wipmania.com/[your_IP_address]

Answer (score 0):

You could use my service: https://SmartIP.io , which provides full country names and city names of any IP address. We also expose timezones, currency, proxy detection, TOR nodes detection and Crypto detection.

You just need to signup and get a free API key which allows for 250,000 requests per month.

Using the official PHP library, the API call becomes:

```php
$apiKey = "your API key";
$smartIp = new SmartIP($apiKey);
$response = $smartIp->requestIPData("8.8.8.8");

echo "\nstatus code: " . $response->{"status-code"};
echo "\ncountry name: " . $response->country->{"country-name"};
```

Check the API documentation for more info:
https://smartip.io/docs

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleaner and working version of the accepted answer using guzzle:

You can use curl instead of guzzle it's just a simple get request.

```php
    function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
        $output = NULL;
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            if ($deep_detect) {
                if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }
        }
        $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
        $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
        $continents = array(
            "AF" => "Africa",
            "AN" => "Antarctica",
            "AS" => "Asia",
            "EU" => "Europe",
            "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
            "NA" => "North America",
            "SA" => "South America"
        );
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support, true)) {
            $client = New \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $ipdat = json_decode($client->request('GET','http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp',$params = [
                'query' => [
                    'ip' => $ip,
                ]
            ])->getBody()->getContents(),true);
            if (strlen(trim($ipdat['geoplugin_countryCode'])) === 2) {
                switch ($purpose) {
                    case "location":
                        $output = array(
                            "city"           => $ipdat['geoplugin_city'],
                            "state"          => $ipdat['geoplugin_regionName'],
                            "country"        => $ipdat['geoplugin_countryName'],
                            "country_code"   => $ipdat['geoplugin_countryCode'],
                            "continent"      => $continents[strtoupper($ipdat['geoplugin_continentCode'])],
                            "continent_code" => $ipdat['geoplugin_continentCode']
                        );
                        break;
                    case "address":
                        $address = array($ipdat['geoplugin_countryName']);
                        if (@strlen($ipdat['geoplugin_regionName']) >= 1)
                            $address[] = $ipdat['geoplugin_regionName'];
                        if (@strlen($ipdat['geoplugin_city']) >= 1)
                            $address[] = $ipdat['geoplugin_city'];
                        $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                        break;
                    case "city":
                        $output = $ipdat['geoplugin_city'];
                        break;
                    case "region":
                    case "state":
                        $output = $ipdat['geoplugin_regionName'];
                        break;
                    case "country":
                        $output = $ipdat['geoplugin_countryName'];
                        break;
                    case "countrycode":
                        $output = $ipdat['geoplugin_countryCode'];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get country as fast as possible I would suggest geoip plugin for your web server.

For nginx [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html);

After you set this up properly, you will get countrycode from `$_SERVER` variable.

I execute this about 500(+-) times per seccond, super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Achieve this with just 4 lines of code!

```
$user_ip = '0.0.0.0';
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$close_url = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
$user_country = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://ipinfo.io/$user_ip/json",false,$close_url));
echo "Yes! we ship to your country: <b>" . $user_country->country . "</b>";
```

//Output Yes! we ship to your country **US**

Note:
**$close_url** is used to end the file_get_contents asap after content has been retrieved, it improves the speed of the request x5.

If you want to show the full country name you can click below and see how.

[enter link description here](https://ipinfo.io/blog/full-country-names)

//echo "Peace to the world";

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this minimal function to get country name with this simple API.

```
include('Curl.php');
echo getCountry('132.xx.xx.xx');

function getCountry($ip){
    $url="http://ip-api.com/php/".$ip;
    $this->curl=New Curl;
    $result=$this->curl->simple_get($url);
    $result=unserialize($result);
      if($result['status']!='fail'){
         return $result['country'];
       }
}
```

I using this [PHP cURL class](https://gist.github.com/nkmswot/3d076fd34b40cc91d17071c4258a452f).