# How to make an automatic country finder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making a registration page on my website.

I don't want my users to type their own country. I am wondering how to make a PHP/JS/jQuery script that will work with this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="!!COUNTRY CODE HERE!!">
```

Comment: No such thing. This requires user interaction. There are geolocation services (paid) that you can use, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Based upon what?  The IP address?

Comment: You can get the position with the HTML5 geolocation API. And then discover to which country this coordinates belong to.

Comment: Yes. IP. I have seen a website using it.

Comment: *"I am wondering how to make a PHP/JS/jQuery script that will work with this:"* – **A:** "Google".

Comment: Google didn't really help. No results are similar to my question.

Comment: Depends on the keyword(s) you used and how long you spent searching. *"Google didn't really help."* Imagine spending 3 days on a problem? Well, that's how long I will search for a solution sometimes and "tried something". ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the users country, you're going to need to do it with (qualified) guess using their IP address - see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600004/2366976) for an easy PHP-script for doing so.

If this is for a user registration page and the users country is important to get right, though, I would recommend a dropdown-menu where the users can choose the country for themselves instead. Guessing which country a user is from based on their IP isn't guaranteed to be correct every time. Some people might be using static IP addresses or VPNs or some proxy of sorts, which would give you a wrong result.