# Find IP to Country Code in php code

Tags: php, ip

hi i want get country code data from ip address 
this site give free services like this link for example
http://freegeoip.net/json/23.94.30.210
this link show all data but i need only `"country_code":"US"` from it.

Please tell me how to implement this link in php get only "country_code":"US" from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/23.94.30.210");
$countryInfo = json_decode($jsonData,true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AIO1IQ).

Answer (score 0):

First, see related question [Getting visitors country from their IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip). You can use [Geo IP Location](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data has been JSON encoded. You will need to use the JSON functions available in PHP to decode this, and retrieve the country code (assuming you've already managed to retrieve the information using cURL).

Here is a sample bit of code:

```
// $data contains the information shown at http://freegeoip.net/json/23.94.30.210.
$decoded = json_decode($data);
$country_code = $decoded['country_code'];
```

Comment: FWIW the freegeoip.net API supports JSON, XML or even CSV.

Comment: yes i use JSON encode for fetch the IP detail from any ip . but any good or other procedure for any other site because its down some time then problem us