# serve different image depending on the ip

Tags: php, image, ip

I am working on an eshop which uses image buttons to show the prices of the products.

I'd like to show different link button images depending the ip of the customer.

This is because we have to have different VAT regarding the country of origin of the customer.

Furthermore the new button should be linked to a different link.

I need something like:

```
php_code_that_identifies_IP
case 1:
<a href="link-to-price-1"><img src="image_1" /></a>
case 2:
<a href="link-to-price-2"><img src="image_2" /></a>
case 3:
.
.
.
..
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600004/1351857
It's using this API http://www.geoplugin.com/examples