# Automatically select state and city according to zip code in Magento's onepage checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I want to select automatically the state and city according to a zipcode in the billing information process bar of one page checkout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip

Answer (score 2):

Use GeoCoding APIs.

For example if you want result for zip **10017**

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=10017+US&sensor=true
```

Here we are passing **ZIP code + Country**. Reason is, some of the zip code returns more than one result. For example - **208006**.

Thanks.

Comment: where i have to use the above GeoCoding APIs?  Please Explain

Comment: You can use Ajax functionality. Either you add a button beside ZIP code field and fire ajax to get the JSON response from Google or you can fire on 'onkeyup' or 'onblur' as per you requirement. Thanks.

Comment: No its not working for me

Comment: How can i get checkout page shipping zipcode?