# How can i restrict acces in my page? Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, restrict

My problem is: I need to restrict access to people from another country such as Japan . As I do so that no one in Japan can go to my website ?

Comment: You should implement a event listener listens to Controller event and do all your logic

Refer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip
and
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://ipinfo.io/ API. The code looks like: (PHP)

```
$allowed_countries = array("IN", "US", ...);
$country = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/country");
if(!in_array($country, $allowed_countries)) 
{
   echo 'Restricted'; //or any error message.
}
```

Comment: Caching IP addresses (or storing them in a DB) and checking your cache (or DB) before making the call each time could speed up page calls.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to detect IP of the user and redirect the user to an error page if the IP is from Japan.

A nice bundle to detect user IP is available here:

https://github.com/aferrandini/Maxmind-GeoIp

To block all you pages at once you could do the IP check inside a Listner that  define the method onKernelRequest. An example visible here :
http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html#request-events-checking-types

Don't forget to register the listener in the services.yml file available in each bundle.

An alternative way to detect japanese users could be to parse the user agent received from the browser and parse it, it will probably contains "ja" or "JP" as a language marker.