# How to redirect Cakephp Applications based on Country code?

Tags: cakephp, redirect, geoip

I have two cakephp applications, cakephp.com and cakephp.in
Based country IP how to redirect cakephp.com to cakephp.in.
For Example if COUNTRY CODE is "IN" , then redirect to cakephp.in and COUNTRY CODE is not equal to "IN" then redirect to cakephp.com

Let me know is there any possibility to do the redirection.

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: You could check for the countrycode in the AppController `beforeFilter()` function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip , use that function to check for country code, and redirect to the correct domain. Be sure to flag that a redirect has occured aswell.

Comment: Cakephp version:2.5.2

Comment: Please try something and describe what problems you've had with your shown-code.