# HTML+CSS autodetect system/browser language

Tags: html, css

I made HTML+CSS file to send via email as newsletter. Working for a portuguese company, I need to deliver the newsletter in portuguese for portuguese people and in english for everybody else. I would like to know if there is some way to make the newsletter to change languages (via XML, maybe) based on a readers system language? If yes, can somebody enlight me how it can be done?

Thank you!

Comment: No, sadly not possible.

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference) out, it´ll maybe help your purpose.

Comment: With php you can get user country like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip

Comment: @DanielLagiň — It's email. What browser?

Comment: @ICE — The user will be reading the email from their email server. You can't run PHP there.

Comment: @Quentin I know that. I mentioned that because he can use it on the newsletter sign up.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The typical way of setting a reasonable default for documents available in multiple languages on the WWW is to examine the Accept header of the HTTP request.

When you are just sending email via SMTP, there is no HTTP request for you to look at, and once it is sent it becomes static.

The best you can do is ask the user *when they sign up* for the newsletter (possibly using the Accept header to set a default if you are asking them on the WWW) what language version of the email they want to receive.