# how to change WHMCS url by country

Tags: php, .htaccess, whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

I am new in whmcs and I want to change the URL by country.

If a customer from the India has a URL like:- `http://example.com/in/` or from the UK have a URL like `http://example.com/uk/`.

I am trying this `.htaccess` file but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^in/(.*).php?(.*) /$1.php&country=india [NC,L,QSA]
```

also I want to change the homepage according to country.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to get the country from users IP address.

Using this PHP function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600004/3284463):

```
// Get user IP
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$user_country_code = ip_info($ip, "Country Code"); // This will be a country code e.g 'IN', 'US'


// Redirect to Location
header('Location:' . "https://example.com/" . $user_country_code);
die();
```

Comment: Thank to your answer but i try this code before .htaccess but not working propely

Comment: @jhon Try adding this code to the top of your `index.php` file

Comment: i am using whmcs not core php

Comment: @jhon try adding this code to `Edit templates/*your active template*/homepage.tpl`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Cloudflare no need to add an extra API just add this code under .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^IN
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:gif|png|jpg|jpeg|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !{REQUEST_URI}^ /?country=india [NC,NE,R,L]
```