# Get user country using php for desktop as well as mobile

Tags: php

I am trying to get visitors location detail, for that i used some php code, please check below link,

[Getting visitors country from their IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip)

but this code is not working while user use mobile device.

Can any one help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance
Omkar

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the geolocation API from HTML5, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation, where you get the location from GPS if the device have GPS and the user has activated it