# Codeigniter : Loading multiple languages with hooks concept, issue is : not able to load/update file of same language

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to load multiple languages in my project so i refers the code from
https://www.codexworld.com/multi-language-implementation-in-codeigniter/comment-page-1/

which use the concept of hooks,
the example of this link is work for me but they only load the 'Message' file or use the single file for single language in LanguageLoader class...
Above ref link example structure :

```
language/
       english/
               message.php
       German/
               message.php
```

but i have to use the separate files for every page of project like

```
language/
        english/
               message1.php
               message2.php
               message3.php
        German/
               message1.php
               message2.php
               message3.php
```

I want to pass the language file name for LanguageLoade class to load separate language file for separate project page

Comment: This may help you. [Link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html)

Comment: @Virb your comment is help full... but i want to set the language according to the access loaction i.e. if the site is access from German then the default language must be set automatically German... for that i found some details about hook concept..

Comment: Extend hook class with method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip).