# PHP: No response when try to proceed a json string

Tags: php, json

PS: This code is modified from [Getting visitors country from their IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip#13600004)

I try to use the ipdata service from https://api.ipdata.co/ but when I try to use PHP to decode the json, nothing happened. Even when I try to print the api response out. Can anyone help me lol..

The php code:

```
function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
$output = NULL;
if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    if ($deep_detect) {
        if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else {
        echo "error [2]";
    }
} else {
    echo "error [1]";
}
$rdata = file_get_contents("http://api.ipdata.co/" . $ip);
echo $rdata;
$ipdat = @json_decode($rdata);
echo $ipdat;
$output = @$ipdat->country_code;
return $output;
}

echo ip_info("Visitor", "country");
```

Comment: Try `https` instead of `http` as your protocol in the URL, just as a sanity check :)

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I tried to use http instead of https, but it doesn't seems to be working loll... I also tried to print out the url, it will prints the url, but nothing else...

Comment: Is this your actual code? `echo ip_info("Visitor", "country");`

Comment: I also tried adding error_reporting(E_ALL) but it is not working either.

Comment: @miknik yes it is my actual code.

Comment: Well it's a little buggy, throws a few errors but your code works for me. Have you got fopen wrappers enabled in your php config?

Comment: @miknik fopen? I thnk i want to check lolllll...

Comment: Hi imgg we had a small outage yesterday morning which might've why you got this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function ip_info($ip = NULL, $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    if ($ip == NULL || !filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            }
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }
        }
    }

    $ch = curl_init("http://ip-api.com/json/".$ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);

    if($result['status'] == "fail"){
        $result = FALSE; /* If an Error has come back, you can use $result['message'] to get why. */
    } 
    else { $result =  $result['countryCode']; } // If Sucess
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The API you were using was slow and also using file_get_contents is not a good idea.

Comment: Not a problem Have fun with it! 
Check the API URL and see what other things you can get.

http://ip-api.com/json/

Comment: @imgg we had an outage yesterday morning which might'be been why you got this. I'm able to run the code in the example from the question you linked to and the php test code on our docs page ipdata.co/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

We had an outage yesterday morning that might've caused this. I've tested the following code and it works for me. Let me know if you have any issues.

```
function ip_info($ip = NULL, $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    if ($ip == NULL || !filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            }
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }
        }
    }

    $ch = curl_init("https://api.ipdata.co/".$ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);

    $result =  $result['country_code'];
    return $result;
}
var_dump(ip_info('1.1.1.1'));
//string(2) "AU"
```

Comment: interesting...! never mind, i have been able to use the ipdata now. thanks for replying!