# certain page(php) appear only in certain country IP

Tags: php, laravel, ip

I want to make certain page(php) appear only in certain country IP.

However, it is possible to designate a few IPs, but it is too cumbersome to specify all IP of certain country one by one.

Of course, I can get the client's IP with laravel or php, but I want to know ip's country.

By default my site can be accessed from all countries. However, I want to make a page that is visible only to IP of a certain country.

Is there anything better?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just only want to know the name of the country that associate with IP address then follow this link [Get Country name from Ip and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip)

But I think the other solution is from the server side.