# How to redirect subdomain based on country in Prestashop?

Tags: php, redirect, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a Prestashop 1.7 website. I want to open a subdomain and put a copy of my site there. But I just want to enter that subfield from country x. In addition, I want to redirect the main site to the subdomain when entering from x countries. Even if site X is visited from another country, I want to redirect it to my main site. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract user's country by their IP address.

Check out this Thread: [Getting visitors country from their IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip)