# PHP: Get the timezone from where the application was accessed

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

Laravel 7.x

I need to access the timezone from where the application was accessed. I am only getting `UTC` in return from `echo date_default_timezone_get();`.

But I need to get something like `Asia/Kolkata` in return. For the access logs.

Comment: This isn't really detectable on the server side, you can GeoLocate the IP address and make a rough guess at the timezone. But that's as accurate as you can get

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Framework: Laravel 7.x

```php
namespace App\Services;

class TimeZoneService
{
    /**
     * Protected Variables
     */
    protected $host   = null;
    protected $filter = null;
    protected $ip     = null;
    protected $json   = null;

    public function __construct($ip, $filter = false)
    {
        $this->ip     = $ip;
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->host   = "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip={$ip}";
    }

    /**
     * fetch the location data via given IP address
     *
     * @return  array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if(function_exists('curl_init'))
        {
            # use cURL to fetch data
            $request = curl_init();

            # setting options
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $this->host);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'geoPlugin PHP Class v1.1');

            # response
            $this->json = curl_exec($request);

            # closing cURL
            curl_close($request);
        }
        else if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen'))
        {
            # fall back to fopen()
            $this->json = file_get_contents($this->host, 'r');
        }
        else
        {
            trigger_error('geoPlugin Error: Cannot retrieve data.', E_USER_ERROR);
            return;
        }

        # returning
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * convert the json string to php array 
     * based on the filter property
     *
     * @return  array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        # condition(s)
        if($this->filter != true)
        {
            return json_decode($this->json, true);
        }

        # filtering & returning
        return $this->__filter();
    }

    /**
     * convert the json string to php object 
     * based on the filter property
     *
     * @return  object
     */
    public function toObject()
    {
        # condition(s)
        if($this->filter != true)
        {
            return json_decode($this->json);
        }

        # filtering & returning
        return (object)$this->__filter();
    }

    /**
     * return collected location data in the form of json
     * based on the filter property
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    public function toJson()
    {
        # condition(s)
        if($this->filter != true)
        {
            return $this->json;
        }

        # filtering & returning
        return json_encode($this->__filter());
    }

    /**
     * filter the object keys
     *
     * @return  array
     */
    private function __filter()
    {
        # applying filter
        foreach(json_decode($this->json, true) as $key => $item)
        {
            $return[str_replace('geoplugin_', '', $key)] = $item;
        }

        # returning
        return $return;
    }
}
```

SomeController.php

```php
/**
 * Services
 */
use App\Services\TimeZoneService;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function someMethod()
    {
        # services
        $TimeZone = new TimeZoneService(<string IP_ADDRESS>, <boolean FILTER>);

        $locationData = $TimeZone->getData()->toJson();
        # OR
        $locationData = $TimeZone->getData()->toArray();
        # OR
        $locationData = $TimeZone->getData()->toObject();

        ...
    }
}
```

This code is working fine for me. However, If you see any room for improvement then please feel free to update the code to help others.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you can only make a guess, but not have 100% sure.

I made some modifications to [Chandra Nakka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4109841/chandra-nakka)'s [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600004/7970301).

It will validate the guess with the [timezone_identifiers_list()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.timezone-identifiers-list.php) function, if it's not a valid timezone, the default will be returned.

```php
function set_timezone_by_client_location($ip = NULL, $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    $output = NULL;
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $continents = array(
        "AF" => "Africa",
        "AN" => "Antarctica",
        "AS" => "Asia",
        "EU" => "Europe",
        "OC" => "Australia",
        "NA" => "America",
        "SA" => "America"
    );
    $timezone = null;
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
        if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
          $timezone = @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)] . '/' . @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
          $timezone = str_replace(' ', '_', $timezone);
        }
    }


    if(!in_array($timezone, timezone_identifiers_list())){
      $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    }

    return $timezone;
}

$timezone = set_timezone_by_client_location();

echo $timezone;
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucius, based on your answer I have created a class of my own. And its working fine for me. I'll post it shortly. Thanks again :)