# How to get Country name from ip address using ipinfo?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel package for getting location using IP Address.

```
composer require ipinfo/ipinfolaravel
```

But when I hit request to get data of location it return null for local host. I have use this,

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->ipinfo->all);
}
```

and get out put as,

```
array:5 [▼
    "ip" => "127.0.0.1"
    "bogon" => true
    "country_name" => null
    "latitude" => null
    "longitude" => null
]
```

and if I use code like this

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->ipinfo->country_name);
}
```

it return

```
null
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip

Comment: I suggest you to use php default function `REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: can you share link example of REMOTE_ADDR #A.A Noman

Comment: Please see this documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I would expect that localhost returns null. It's always the same IP wherever you live