# Dynamically retrieve user country to rectrict results from Google Places API

Tags: location, google-places-api, google-places, country-codes

I'm developing my personal project and I'm working for first time with the Google Places API - I would like to retrict the user's post/search to each user's country.

So I need visitor from Australia just been able to get address results for "au", basically, but for each country.

Is there anything easier that this [Getting visitors country from their IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip) to retrieve the visitors country and pass it as the componentRestrictions? Is it the best/recommendable way to do it?

Thanks ahead!

```
function initialize() {

 var input = document.getElementById('address');
  var options = {
   // fields: ["address_components", "geometry"],
    strictBounds: false,
    types: ["address"],
  componentRestrictions: { country: ["au","nz"] }
   };  
  
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
```

I forgot to mention that I'm using Nominatim to display the user location so maybe better using this to restrict?

```
 data.address['country_code']
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by passing the nominatim country_code (I use that to retrieve user's location) to the Google component via geoLocationSuccess():

```
function geoLocationSuccess(pos) {
  // get user lat,long  
  var myLat = pos.coords.latitude,
    myLng = pos.coords.longitude,
    loadingTimeout;

  var loading = function () {
     $address.val("Fetching location...");   
  };

  loadingTimeout = setTimeout(loading, 600);

  var request = $.get(
    "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=" +
      myLat +
      "&lon=" +
      myLng
  )
    .done(function (data) {
                            
      if (loadingTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(loadingTimeout);
        loadingTimeout = null;

        
        // Restrict Google Places API to this country?
        var countrycode = data.address['country_code'];
         var input = document.getElementById('address');
          var options = {
           // fields: ["address_components", "geometry"],
            strictBounds: false,
            types: ["address"],
          componentRestrictions: { country: countrycode }
           };  
  
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
      
     
     }
    })
    .fail(function () {
      // handle error
     alertify.error('We can´t access your device location.');
     $address.val("Type your location");         
    });

}
```