# Can i trust the value that is returned from ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a IIS hosted ASP.NET WebAPI app and im using `ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to get the client address and identify the user: client logs in and i will generate a cookie that contains the client IP. In subsequent calls i will get the IP from the cookie, and validate that it is correct.

Can i trust the address, or is there a way that `ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` returns e.g. `161.121.222.223` and the client is really somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, it's safe. It is the source IP of the TCP connection and can't be substituted by changing an HTTP header.
>
> One case you may want to be worry of is if you are behind a reverse proxy in which case the REMOTE_ADDR will always be the IP of the proxy server and the user IP will be provided in an HTTP header (such as X-Forwarded-For). But for the normal use case reading REMOTE_ADDR is fine.

Taken from: [Is it safe to trust $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773969/is-it-safe-to-trust-serverremote-addr)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's reliable. It can't be modified by the client, except by simply connecting from another IP. (Proxy)