# Is this login structure safe from SQL injection?

Tags: php, authentication

I want to / am busy with completely re-writing my whole site. At this point I am working on what I call "members- and safety engine". I have been reading a lot about security and SQL injection, and it is pretty complicated.
ps. My site is more a hobby than a professional money making website with about 250+ members.

For username AND password I only allow the characters a-z, A-Z and 0-9. I check this in the `if(isset(post))`-function with:

```
if(ctype_alnum(mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($string))) == false) {
    header to error-page; exit;}
else {continu with script}
```

This check is done for both the password and the username.

When somebody tries to login with a unknown username or a known username with a wrong password the action is logged (inserted) in a special table, including IP address. After 10 attempts to login with an unknown username, or 6 attempts with a wrong password the IP address is blocked from the members area and on all the non-member pages forms and submit of the forms are not shown and they are not useable because of this ip-block. I even have this ip-check as a line when the form is submitted... if the ip is in the table, header(to error page); exit;.

My questions:

- Do I have to make a security check when I place the
  IP address in a string? `$xip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` this `$xip` is
  inserted in the table when trying to log in with a unknown user or
  with wrong password.
- Is this a (pretty) safe environment against hacking and SQL injection?
- If not? I really appreciate help and suggestions (writing the complete solution here is very much appreciated, but I learn a lot
  more when you send me on the right path to the solution)
- Do I also have to run the "ctype_alnum" check when I retrieve this info from the `$_cookie` or the `$_session`?

ps. I am dutch, so almost all of my table names, column names, form input-field-names etc etc etc have a dutch word for it. I am still working on it, but when the site is finished you will not find the word "password", "pass", "user", "userid", or anything like that on my site.

Comment: If you're rewriting your whole site, then rewrite it using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements rather than rewriting it with the MySQL library

Answer (score 1):

Using prepared statements with MySQLi or PDO is a must as a first step to preventing SQL injection, and the mysql_* commands are deprecated anyway.

But, the best place to answer your questions for best practices at preventing SQL Injection would be OWASP: They have many great resources for both general methodologies and review of code, as well as language-specific guidelines and libraries.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_SQL_Injection
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reviewing_Code_for_SQL_Injection

Answer (score 0):

1. No you don't have to, this variable is safe. Have a look at : [Is it safe to trust serverremot addr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773969/is-it-safe-to-trust-serverremote-addr)
2. It depends, you will have to post the entire authentication code
3. Usually a good practice is to select every users from the DB, then iterate over them and compare username/password in order to find a match. That way you don't need to place user input in the SQL statement.
4. It depends what you do with the content of these

Comment: thanx very much. at 2. what do you mean with "you will have to post the entire authentication code"? and at 4. i guess... when i use this retrieved info from cookie or session within a form i should do the ctype_alnum check, otherwise it is save to use.

Comment: Well your question focuses on the user authentication part so it's pretty hard to tell if it's safe without looking at it.
Now concerning the $_COOKIE and $_SESSION array's members, you want to take care of them if they are used in an SQL statement, especially for the $_COOKIE array. Using prepared statement is definitively a must since you can get rid of all the the evil that might be encapsulated into your variables.