# htaccess changes have effects on PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, bots

I have been using `file_get_contents` for a while for embed WP. It works well, but now we have a Hacker-Bot coming from `akh-ari-nat.front.d0m.de` and sending the local IP 192.168.48.6. So we decide to block the Hostname using htaccess.

As soon as I add this in my htaccess:

```
deny from akh-ari-nat.front.d0m.de
```

`file_get_contents` stops working in my index.php. Does someone know why?

Comment: does it give you any error feedback?

Comment: no just a clean site... i now try to stop php with this: 

`if(gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == "akh-ari-nat.front.d0m.de") { die(); } `
in the fist line, but with the same result. 
Maybe the Bot is on the Server?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4773981/3536236) may give you some clues